# ASP.NET MVC multiple query string parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I design my URL to match my function like this:

```
public ActionResult GetStuff(string name, string address, double latitude, double longitude)
{ }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a route with a signature that has all those parameters in it.

```
routes.MapRoute("myRoute",
                "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{address}/{latitude}/{longitude}",
                new { controller = "Home", 
                      action = "GetStuff", 
                      latitude=0.0, 
                      longitude =0.0, address="", name = "" }
           );
```

If you just intend to POST data to that action method, then the parameter names in your method signature can just match named input fields on your form instead.

Comment: It will also work with the default route, by putting all the extra values as query values: /controller/action?name=a&address=b&latitude=c&longitude=d